# looping in c# threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, infinite-loop

Im developing a web app in c#. This app uses an API from other application wich returns an Array of objects that I want to convert to datatable. The first version of my app uses a for loop to add all the objects in the Array to the datatable one by one. This version does the job correctly but takes some time to process.

So i've decided to go on multithreading and reduce the time to process, since the server im going to deploy my app has several cores. However i want to create threads dinamically for scalability and reusability of the code in future projects.

When I execute the app, first time it runs pretty cool, the second time it gets looped. The error I'm having appears to be an infinite loop inside the threads, however don't have a clue where can it be.

Halp anyone pls. Below is my code:

Hilos2.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Hilos2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Hilos2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:GridView id="gvrandom" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hilos2.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data;

public partial class Hilos2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    clsValues[] vals = new clsValues[1038];

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ds.Tables.Add("Out");

            ds.Tables["Out"].Columns.AddRange(new[] { new     DataColumn("Value1", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("Value2", typeof(string)) });

            /*this section is just to represent the array i get from the api
            the size of the array are similar*/
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1038; i++)
            {
                vals[i] = new clsValues();
                vals[i].Value1 = Convert.ToChar(rand.Next(1, 256)).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(rand.Next(1, 256)).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(rand.Next(1, 256)).ToString() +
                    Convert.ToChar(rand.Next(1, 256)).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(rand.Next(1, 256)).ToString();
                vals[i].Value2 = Convert.ToChar(rand.Next(1, 256)).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(rand.Next(1, 256)).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(rand.Next(1, 256)).ToString() +
                    Convert.ToChar(rand.Next(1, 256)).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(rand.Next(1, 256)).ToString();
            }

            int elementsXthread = (int)Math.Truncate((double)(vals.Length / Environment.ProcessorCount));
            int elementsLastThread;
            int elementsToProcess;
            int posStartProcess = 0;
            List<Thread> thr = new List<Thread>();

            if (elementsXthread * Environment.ProcessorCount != vals.Length)
            {
                elementsLastThread = elementsXthread + vals.Length - (elementsXthread * Environment.ProcessorCount);
            }
            else
            {
                elementsLastThread = elementsXthread;
            }

            elementsToProcess = elementsXthread;

            for (int i = 1; i < Environment.ProcessorCount + 1; i++)
            {
                if (i == Environment.ProcessorCount)
                {
                    elementsToProcess = elementsLastThread;
                }
                if (elementsToProcess + posStartProcess <= vals.Length)
                {
                    int param1, param2;
                    param1 = elementsToProcess;
                    param2 = posStartProcess;
                    Thread tdr = new Thread(() => rnd(param1, param2));
                    tdr.Start();
                    thr.Add(tdr);
                    posStartProcess += elementsToProcess;
                }
            }
            foreach (Thread tdr in thr)
            {
                tdr.Join();
            }

            gvrandom.DataSource = ds.Tables["Out"];
            gvrandom.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private void rnd(int iter, int posinicio)
    {

        for (int iterador = 0; iterador < iter; iterador++)
        {
            System.Data.DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Out"].NewRow();
            dr["Value1"] = vals[iterador + posinicio].Value1;
            dr["Value2"] = vals[iterador + posinicio].Value2;
            ds.Tables["Out"].Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
}
public class clsValues
{
    string value1, value2;

    public string Value1
    {
        get
        {
            return value1;
        }
        set
        {
            value1 = value;
        }
    }

    public string Value2
    {
        get
        {
            return value2;
        }
        set
        {
            value2 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the real question is why you are showing the user 1000+ objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that you're modifying a `DataTable` from multiple threads. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) says:

> This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must synchronize any write operations.

So you have multiple threads all blindly updating the table. If two or more of them try to do an update at the same time, the results are unpredictable. They're likely *not* what you want.

If you go ahead and do the synchronization, I'd be very surprised to see that the multithreaded version runs faster than the single-threaded version. If all your threads do is add stuff to the table, then they'll spend most of their time waiting on the lock. You'd get no benefit from using multiple threads because the threads aren't doing much in parallel.

In short, using multiple threads in this case just isn't a win. Save yourself the trouble and do this with a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't preventing thread contention.   The threads are all colliding as they interact with ds.

A. Declare a lock.

```
private object myLock = new object();
```

B. Use lock in rand method :

```
 private void rnd(int iter, int posinicio)
 {

    for (int iterador = 0; iterador < iter; iterador++)
    {
        System.Data.DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Out"].NewRow();
        dr["Value1"] = vals[iterador + posinicio].Value1;
        dr["Value2"] = vals[iterador + posinicio].Value2;
        lock (myLock)
        {
            ds.Tables["Out"].Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad way to implement multi-threading especially in ASP.NET application and no thread safety at all.

However a better approach is to use `PageAsyncTask` which is designed and created specifically for such cases, reference:

[MSDN PageAsyncTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pageasynctask(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: The threads aren't waiting for each other. The main thread is waiting on all threads to finish. His problem isn't that the threads are waiting, but rather that the threads are all modifying a data structure that cannot safely be modified concurrently by multiple threads.

Comment: oh yah i misread the code , i thought he was joining each thread with the other one not the main thread, thx for the info, however my point still stands about lack of thread safety and using PageAsyncTask is better approach.